# Can I open a link starts with chrome:// or brave://?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have created a chrome extension, and I want to provide a link to help user configurate it, `href="chrome://extensions/shortcuts"`, but when I click on it, it will throw an error in console, saying `Not allowed to load local resource`.

I guess loading this page is forbidden due to security reason,is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Add a listener for `click` event and open that url as chrome.tabs.create({url: '....'})

Comment: Seems like that passing through that is not possible as well, prohibited as the doc say: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create

Comment: You're linking Firefox documentation but Firefox doesn't even have this URL. It works in Chrome.

Comment: Right just tried out, it works in chrome. I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/webextension-polyfill, instead of using `chrome` directly, which I thought it will not work.